# Vulnerability with scanf ( "%s", string)

Tags: c

I have this code in C language

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int foo () {printf ("foo \n");return 1;}
int bar () {printf ("bar \n");return 1;}

typedef struct {
   char buf[20];
   int (*func)();
} Object ;

int main()
{
    Object *o1 , *o2;
    o1 = (Object*) malloc (sizeof(Object));
    o2 = (Object*) malloc (sizeof(Object));

    if(o1==NULL || o2==NULL)
        return -1;

    o1-> func =&foo;
    o2-> func =&bar;
    scanf ( "%s " , o1->buf);
    scanf ( "%s " , o2->buf);

    (* ( o1->func ))();
    (* ( o2->func ))();

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, it crashes

The problem is in this two line:

```
scanf ( "%s " , o1->buf);
scanf ( "%s " , o2->buf);
```

It has a vulnerability in this two line.

**updated :**

this is an example of result :

[image]

the program run without error but I think a Vulnerability exist in the scanf line

Comment: What input did you enter?

Comment: If you want to protect against input that is too long use `%19s` or use `fgets` instead of `scanf`.

Comment: Why do you have a space after your format in `scanf`? `scanf` will read upto the first space it finds.

Comment: the space after %s  cause problem and with this an attacker may exploit it

Answer (score 2):

From `man scanf`:

> **`int scanf(const char *format, ...);`**
>
> The `format` string consists of a **sequence of directives** which describe how to process the sequence of input characters. <snip>       A directive is one of the following:
>
> - A **sequence of white-space characters** (space, tab, newline, etc.; see isspace(3)).  **This directive matches any amount of white space, including none, in the input.**
> - An ordinary character (i.e., one other than white space or '%').  This character must exactly match the next character of input.
> - A  conversion  specification, which commences with a '%' (percent) character.  A sequence of characters from the input is converted according to this specification
>
> **Conversion specification:** **`s`**: Matches a sequence of **non-white-space characters**; the next pointer must be a pointer to character array that is long enough to hold the input sequence **and the terminating null byte (`\0`)**, which is added automatically.  The input string stops at white space or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first.

So when you write:

```
scanf("%s ",buf)
```

The function will scan for a string and absorb all following white-space characters (including your newlines). This implies that an input from stdin can only terminate by a non-white-space character followed by a new-line:

```
foo      < string conversion specification + absorbed newline
         < absorbed newline
         < absorbed newline
b        < end of white-space directive
```

So in short if you want to ensure that your scanf works as expected, you can do:

```
scanf("%s",buf)
```

You have to make sure that the entered string can fit the size of `buf`, including the NULL character.

If you hardcoded the size of `buf`, you can use something like:

```
scanf("%19s",buf)
```

if `buf` has a size of 20. This way it will read maximum 19 characters and store them in buf with an additional null.